# Get outlook appointments from pst without outlook installed

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to get the appointments from a pst file without outlook installed. It can be with the help of a 3rd party API as long as it's free (unlike independetsoft).
I really need this to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Mozilla Sunbird? 
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2479/mozilla_sunbird_import_outlook_calendar_appointments/

They also appear to have a portable app version that u can run from a USB stick.

http://portableapps.com/apps/office/sunbird_portable

Comment: That's cool but i want to extract the appointments from another pst file and without having the dependency of an MS Office. I can get my outlook appointments just fine. BTW the Mozilla project download link doesn't work, it says "file not found"

Comment: hmm..you're right.  Looks like Sunbird is being replaced by Lightning.  Both of which require an export from Outlook.  Interestingly it appears that Microsoft has a sdk for Outlook..just need someone to write an app that uses it.